# How do I find the explore(s) using a specific view in Looker?

Tags: looker

I have this view file in front of me and I want to query a couple of dimensions and measures from it. How do I find the explore(s) that contain this view?

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1. Use the project find-and-replace to search for the name of the view
2. Rename the view and see which explores have LookML validation errors

Comment: I tried 2. and it worked thank you!! Would you also be able to help me with this looker sql question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73215001/if-statement-and-case-when-statement-with-two-conditions-used-together?noredirect=1#comment129304882_73215001

Comment: What is wrong with Simeon's answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/73215329/10813082

Answer (score 0):

Explores are only visible if it is declared in `models`.

Let's say you have a `data_test.view` in a project, you will need to declare an explore corresponding this view in the models file as follow:

```html
explore: data_test {
from: data_test
label: "Data Test" 
}
```

Once you have validated the LookML with the new declaration, you should be able to find the Explore named "Data Test" in your browser and go nuts on the queries.

Comment: Thank you so much! Would you also be able to help me with this looker sql question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73215001/if-statement-and-case-when-statement-with-two-conditions-used-together?noredirect=1#comment129304882_73215001