# IF statement and CASE WHEN statement with two conditions used together

Tags: mysql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, looker

I would like to achieve the following in looker SQL (hence the `$`):

- If my `count ${count_students} > 0` and the `${subject} is NOT ('Biology')` then the `cost` of the `class` should be provided.

  - ...however if my `count ${count_students} = 0` and the `${subject} is NOT ('Biology')` then the `cost` of the `class` should be divided by 2.
- Secondly, if the results of the `case when` statement is `> $100.00`, I'd like the value to be capped at `$100.00`.

I'm getting an error message because I'm probably not using this two condition CASE WHEN statement correctly and probably also because I'm not wrapping it into the if statement
correctly.

```sql
IF(
    (
        CASE
            WHEN ${count_students} > 0 AND ${subject} NOT IN ('Biology') THEN ( ${costs_of_class} )
            WHEN ${count_students} = 0 AND ${subject} NOT IN ('Biology') THEN ( ${costs_of_class} / 2 ) END
    ) > 100,
    100,
      0
)
```

Comment: It's called `IFF` not `IF`: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html

Comment: However `IFF` is just shorthand for `CASE WHEN` anyway, so you can simplify your expression a lot.

Comment: @Dai Thank you for pointing out. I'm not sure what that would look like using a case when statement only. Can you help me?

Comment: Also, what should happen when _neither_ of your `CASE WHEN` cases match?

Comment: Please post your **full** query (with all of your `SELECT`, `FROM`, `JOIN`, etc clauses)

Comment: Is `${count_students}` a JS interpolated string value, a MySQL query parameter, or a column expression?

Comment: @Dai I'm trying to create this in looker using snowflake sql so there is no SELECT FROM JOIN etc. All the dimensions I'm using in this statement already exist. I have got more conditions that should match all possible cases. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of what you see? How do you add subqueries or CTEs if you can't edit the `FROM` part?

Answer (score 4):

So your existing SQL is like this:

```
SELECT 
    count_students
    ,subject
    ,costs_of_class
    ,CASE
        WHEN count_students > 0 AND subject NOT IN ('Biology') THEN costs_of_class 
        WHEN count_students = 0 AND subject NOT IN ('Biology') THEN costs_of_class / 2 
    END as case_val
    ,iff(case_val > 100, 100, 0) as final_val
from values
(0, 'Biology', 20),
(0, 'NOT_Biology', 30),
(1, 'Biology', 50),
(1, 'NOT_Biology', 70)
t(count_students, subject, costs_of_class)
```

which gives:

| COUNT_STUDENTS | SUBJECT | COSTS_OF_CLASS | CASE_VAL | FINAL_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Biology | 20 | null | 0 |
| 0 | NOT_Biology | 30 | 15 | 0 |
| 1 | Biology | 50 | null | 0 |
| 1 | NOT_Biology | 70 | 70 | 0 |

what you are wanting is LEAST so you don't have to use the SQL to repeat the CASE logic:

```
SELECT 
    count_students
    ,subject
    ,costs_of_class
    ,CASE
        WHEN count_students > 0 AND subject NOT IN ('Biology') THEN costs_of_class 
        WHEN count_students = 0 AND subject NOT IN ('Biology') THEN costs_of_class / 2 
        ELSE -1 -- what value do you want to use here??
    END as case_val
    ,least(case_val, 100) as final_val
from values
(0, 'Biology', 20),
(0, 'NOT_Biology', 30),
(1, 'Biology', 50),
(1, 'NOT_Biology', 70),
(0, 'Biology', 220),
(0, 'NOT_Biology', 230),
(1, 'Biology', 250),
(1, 'NOT_Biology', 270)
t(count_students, subject, costs_of_class)
```

giving:

| COUNT_STUDENTS | SUBJECT | COSTS_OF_CLASS | CASE_VAL | FINAL_VAL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Biology | 20 | -1 | -1 |
| 0 | NOT_Biology | 30 | 15 | 15 |
| 1 | Biology | 50 | -1 | -1 |
| 1 | NOT_Biology | 70 | 70 | 70 |
| 0 | Biology | 220 | -1 | -1 |
| 0 | NOT_Biology | 230 | 115 | 100 |
| 1 | Biology | 250 | -1 | -1 |
| 1 | NOT_Biology | 270 | 270 | 100 |

As long as you solve for the default case and what you want to do with `Biology` classes.

Thus in your form:

```
LEAST( 
    CASE
        WHEN ${count_students} > 0 AND ${subject} NOT IN ('Biology') THEN ( ${costs_of_class} )
        WHEN ${count_students} = 0 AND ${subject} NOT IN ('Biology') THEN ( ${costs_of_class} / 2 ) 
    END,
    100)
```

Answer (score 0):

The code was almost correct, the conditional function is called [IFF](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/iff.html):

> Single-level if-then-else expression. Similar to CASE, but only allows a single condition.

```
IFF(
  (CASE
    WHEN ${count_students} > 0 AND ${subject} NOT IN ('Biology') THEN (${costs_of_class})
    WHEN ${count_students} = 0 AND ${subject} NOT IN ('Biology') THEN (${costs_of_class}/2) 
  END) > 100,
  100,
  0
)
```